# How to query for 'First showed up as'

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

Given the following table:

```
 Date       Trd (INT(10))   Code (VARCHAR(10))  T-Date
 1-Jan-14   1               B                   1-Nov-13
 1-Jan-14   2               B                   3-Oct-13
 1-Jan-14   2               B                   3-Oct-13
 2-Jan-14   1               A                   1-Nov-13
 2-Jan-14   2               A                   3-Oct-13
 2-Jan-14   2               A                   3-Oct-13
 2-Jan-14   3               A                   2-Jan-14
 3-Jan-14   2               A                   3-Oct-13
 3-Jan-14   2               A                   3-Oct-13
 3-Jan-14   3               A                   2-Jan-14
 3-Jan-14   4               C                   3-Jan-14
```

How do I `SELECT`, to get the following result:

```
 Date       Trd (INT(10))   First showed up as Code   In Date       T-Date
 3-Jan-14   2               B                         1-Jan-14      3-Oct-13
 3-Jan-14   3               A                         2-Jan-14      2-Jan-14
 3-Jan-14   4               C                         3-Jan-14      3-Jan-14
```

So for a given `Date` (in this case Jan-3rd), `GROUP BY Trd` and find out with which `Code` it first showed up, and provide the `Date` that happened.

I have no idea where to start.

Comment: What is the primary key of the table?

Comment: I dont think you need `GROUP BY trd` since the main criterion is `Code`.Where is trd 1 if you need  `GROUP BY trd`?

Comment: VARCHAT() - French cat-based data types!

Comment: @Mihai he means `WHERE date='2014-01-03' GROUP BY Trd`. There is no Trd=1 in that date.

Comment: There is no B for 3-Jan-14 in your sample.

Comment: Where do you get indate from?

Comment: @ Ypercode. Sorry I omitted the primary key indeed as many other columns. Its just `ID INT(11) unsigned auto_increment unique not null`. Should I include it?

Comment: @ Mihai and @ypercube. Indeed I'm just guessing that I have to `group by`. My point in just not to see `Trd` '2' twice in the output (as its shows in `Date` jan-3.

Comment: @ Mihai. I just edited the table to make sure its clear. The whole problem is that indeed in Jan-3 the `Code` for `Trd`=2 is no longer 'B' but 'A'. However, i need the query to find the original `Code` (='B') and also tell me which date it's from.(=Jan 1st). Makes sense?

Comment: @ Mihai. `In Date` is the first `Date` that the `Trd`=2 appears (min Date where Trd=2?).

Comment: I dont get it. You want to group by trd where date is some date but if one code is missing you want to get it from somewhere else on what condition?For results you need some sort of consistency,you cant pick and choose.

Comment: @ Mihai. If I was not clear about this: I don't care what the `Code` is now, I need to know what is was when it first appeared (min `Date`). Indeed that's the key question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, find the `Trd` values for the specific date (using either `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT`):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Trd
FROM tableX
WHERE Date = '2014-01-03' ;
```

Then you can use the above as the "driving" subquery to get the first appearance of these `Trd` values. Basically, this type of queries is often called [`[greatest-n-per-group]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) (there's even a tag at SO!) There are many ways to be done, depending on how you want ties to be shown - and resolved. The following shows only one result per `Trd` and resolves ties on `Date` by using the `ID` column:

```
SELECT 
    '2014-01-03' AS Date,
    t.Trd,
    t.Code,
    t.Date       AS InDate,
    t.T_Date 
FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT Trd
      FROM tableX
      WHERE Date = '2014-01-03' 
    ) AS dt
  JOIN tableX AS t
    ON  t.ID =
        ( SELECT ti.ID
          FROM tableX AS ti
          WHERE ti.Trd = dt.Trd
          ORDER BY ti.Date,
                   ti.ID
          LIMIT 1
        ) ;
```

Two indexes, on `(Date, Trd)` and on `(Trd, Date, ID)` would help efficiency.

Comment: This is a max once a month query so I don't care much about performance. Still, its runs for over 12 hours and never finishes (`show processlist` tells me it is still running). Didn't want to change anything for this query but think I will have to index `Trd` to make it work. This is a single-table DB composed of 360 10k lines x 61 cols csv files. Any thought?

Comment: I've edited with index suggestions. How many different values of `Trd` does the distinct subquery return (in average)?

Comment: 31200 if I run for 2014-01-03, I would guess no more then 60k overall in the database. Will try the indexes...

Comment: Works! Not to mention the query + the indexes amount for quite a quick SQL class.

Comment: So, how does it perform with the indexes? From 12+ hours, down to?

Comment: Its brutal. From 12+ hours to less then 10 sec. The downside of course indexing made uploading quite slower,  still a fair price to pay.

Answer (score 0):

My solution using SQL Server is as below. I could not test it in mysql as my ubuntu server is down. Also, I am not sure if mysql implements cte and window functions yet. In such case you may have to re-write the query as a stored procedure.

```
--Table definition

create table test
(f_date date,
trd int,
code varchar(10),
t_date date);

--Populate table

insert into test
values
 ('1-Jan-14',   1,          'B',                  '1-Nov-13'),
 ('1-Jan-14',   2,          'B',                  '3-Oct-13'),
 ('1-Jan-14',   2,          'B',                  '3-Oct-13'),
 ('2-Jan-14',   1,          'A',                  '1-Nov-13'),
 ('2-Jan-14',   2,          'A',                  '3-Oct-13'),
 ('2-Jan-14',   2,          'A',                  '3-Oct-13'),
 ('2-Jan-14',   3,          'A',                  '2-Jan-14'),
 ('3-Jan-14',   2,          'A',                  '3-Oct-13'),
 ('3-Jan-14',   2,          'A',                  '3-Oct-13'),
 ('3-Jan-14',   3,          'A',                  '2-Jan-14'),
 ('3-Jan-14',   4,          'C',                  '3-Jan-14');


--Quey code

 ; with cte as
 (select RANK()over(partition by trd order by f_date) as rank_no, trd, code, f_date
 from dbo.test) 
 select distinct test.f_date as 'Date', cte.trd as 'Trd', cte.code as 'First showed up as code',
 cte.f_date as 'In Date', test.t_date as 'T-Date'
 from test
 join
 cte on  test.trd = cte.trd
 where test.f_date = '20140103'
 and cte.rank_no = 1;

--Results

Date    Trd First showed up as code In Date T-Date
2014-01-03  2   B   2014-01-01  2013-10-03
2014-01-03  3   A   2014-01-02  2014-01-02
2014-01-03  4   C   2014-01-03  2014-01-03
```

Answer (score 0):

Workable mysql solution is as below.

```
SELECT Date, Trd, Code as 'First showed up as code',
InDate as 'In Date', TDate as 'T-Date' from (
SELECT s.f_date as 'Date', t.trd as 'Trd', t.code as 'Code',
  t.f_date as 'InDate', s.t_date as 'TDate',
   @date:=CASE WHEN @trd <> t.trd THEN 0 ELSE @date+1 END AS rn,
   @trd:=t.trd AS trdset
FROM
  (SELECT @date:= -1) s,
  (SELECT @trd:= -1) c,
  (SELECT *
   FROM test
   ORDER BY trd, f_date
  ) as t
join test as s
on s.trd = t.trd) as o
where rn = 0
and Date = '20140103';
```